Can the "Tree of Life" be conceived as "all trees that bear fruit" in the Holy Realm?
The "tree of life" sustains the eternity of life. When Adam and Eve were expelled from Eden, in Genesis 3:22, the Lord commanded that Eden be guarded so they could not take its fruit and live forever. More clarity about the "tree of life" is found in Revelation 22:1-2, which states:

Then the angel showed me the river of the water of life, as clear as crystal, flowing from the throne of God and of the Lamb 2 down the middle of the great street of the city. On each side of the river stood the tree of life, bearing twelve crops of fruit, yielding its fruit every month. And the leaves of the tree are for the healing of the nations.

Consider that the New Jerusalem spans four thousands miles square, the tree of life should be present throughout the entire area, not just along the riverbanks, to ensure that everyone living there has easy access.
Recall from Genesis 3:2, when Eve replies to the serpent, she says, "We may eat fruit from the trees in the garden, except the tree that is in the middle of the garden".
Therefore, is it reasonable to conceive that the "tree of life" represents "all trees that bear fruit" in the Holy Realm?

I do not believe this question is answerable - we do not have enough information.

@Dottard - the Scripture does not provide all the answers. We engage in an exchange of thoughts as no one has a definitive answer. Otherwise, we would see only one commentary.


"Therefore, is it reasonable to conceive that the "tree of life"
represents "all trees that bear fruit" in the Holy Realm?"

I believe the answer is indeed yes!
The quotes below is from an English translation of a Hebrew rather than a Greek version of the book of Revelation discovered in a Jewish synagogue in Cochin, India 1803/1806. Some scholars believe that this is a copy of the original version of Revelation based on significant linguistic evidence. In addition, there is abundant evidence that the Hebrew Revelation manuscript was NOT translated from the Greek version because the Cochin manuscripts are different in many aspects. Briefly, the familiar Greek version of Revelation reads like the Amplified Bible (AMP) with its multiple word choices and elaborations, while the Cochin Hebrew version is  more direct and terse, when compared side-by-side.
Let’s consider the text in question. The first quote is from the ESV:

Then the angel showed me the river of the water of life, bright as
crystal, flowing from the throne of God and of the Lamb through the
middle of the street of the city; also, on either side of the river,
the tree of life with its twelve kinds of fruit, yielding its fruit
each month. The leaves of the tree were for the healing of the
nations. – Revelation 22:1,2 ESV

And the next two quotes are two different translations of the Cochin Hebrew text:

Then one river was shown to me full of living waters - pure, like
amethyst, coming from the throne of YHWH and the Lamb. And in the
middle of the streets and on the river, every tree of food and the
Tree of Life will grow on its border. And there will be twelve species
of fruit on it; for its fruit will be for food and its leaves will be
medicine. – Revelation 22:1,2 Ms. Oo.1.16 and Ms. Oo.1.32, the
Cambridge University Library, translation by Miles R. Jones


Then he showed me a stream which was full of living waters, and it was
clear like crystal, coming out of the throne of Yahweh and the Lamb.
In the midst of the plains, even beside the stream, there grew up on
its bank – on this side and on that side – every tree of food, even
the tree of life. And on it were twelve kinds of fruit, and its fruit
was for food, and its foliage for healing. – Revelation 22:1,2 Ms.
Oo.1.16 and Ms. Oo.1.32, the Cambridge University Library, translation
by Justin J. Van Rensburg

Thus, in the Hebrew version, many trees bearing fruit will grow in the middle of the streets and on both banks of this river. Wow!
The New Jerusalem
Regarding the answer provided by Peter Kirkpatrick, let me add the following calculations based on both the Greek and the Cochin Hebrew versions.

And the one who spoke with me had a measuring rod of gold to measure
the city and its gates and walls. The city lies foursquare, its length
the same as its width. And he measured the city with his rod, 12,000
stadia. Its length and width and height are equal. He also measured
its wall, 144 cubits by human measurement, which is also an angel's
measurement. – Revelation 21:15-17 ESV

The actual size of the New Jerusalem is enormous when measured in Greek stadia . . . 1,380 miles on each side! Its 2D footprint would cover most of the Middle East and modeling it in AutoCAD demonstrates that it would fit comfortably inside the Moon with its eight corners sticking out 116 miles from the Moon's surface. This cube has a volume almost exactly half that of the Moon. Its height would be taller than what’s considered a low-earth orbit of a satellite.

But here's the translation from the Cochin manuscript:

"And he who spoke with me had a reed of gold in his hand, to measure
with it the city and the wall and the gates. And the city lay as a
square, and its length was the same as its width, and he measured the
city with the reed, twelve thousand graves of the field . . ."

The reference to “graves of the field” is bizarre, but the distance turns out to be around one reed. But what’s one reed?
Lengths of linear measurement in the Bible include the cubit, the long cubit, and the reed (or rod). The book of Revelation includes many references and allusions to the Tanakh. Could there be a connection here?
Here’s a prophetic excerpt from the book of Ezekiel.

And behold, there was a wall all around the outside of the temple
area, and the length of the measuring reed in the man's hand was six
long cubits, each being a cubit and a handbreadth in length. So he
measured the thickness of the wall, one reed; and the height, one
reed. – Ezekiel 40:5 ESV

A cubit is the length from elbow to the finger tips, normally about 18 inches or a little less. A long cubit, which is also the Egyptian royal cubit used in ancient architecture, adds a handbreadth or three inches to the cubit, making it a “long” cubit of 21 inches. Thus, a measuring reed according to Ezekiel is six long cubits or 10-1/2 feet in length.
The 12,000 of these reeds/rods (rather than Greek stadia) would be a length of about 23.86 miles on a side, which is about the same area as Dallas, Texas.
Thus, if the New Jerusalem were superimposed and centered on Jerusalem, and rotated 20 degrees to parallel a side of the Dead Sea, we would see the following on a map:

These dimensions are far more reasonable, although the height would still be problematic at over four times the height of Mount Everest! The earth’s atmosphere is breathable at not much higher than Mount Everest. While this height is much smaller than before, it still seems improbable and further study is needed.
Perhaps, the phrase “and the height” was added later at some point, or it might also be interpreted differently, for example as a poetic euphemism for honor.
Incidentally, the "Dallas dimensions" of the new Jerusalem significantly exceed those in Ezekiel 48, which are given as only about 1.28 miles on a side. They also exceed the less-than three-mile width of the set-apart (holy) portion described. Thus, the New Jerusalem comes down from the heavens at a later point in time.
But the text is what it is, and so let’s leave this question unresolved for now.

Consider 21:1,5. New heavens and new earth... I make all things new. You can debate exactly what that means, I don't insist on any particular interpretation, but Revelation describes a lot of catastrophic events that have to be undone somehow. It seems fairly trivial for God at the same time to resolve problems such as "not enough oxygen at altitude", assuming the upper regions are actually supposed to be inhabited (it could just be the height of the walls, for example).

Thanks Dieter. Your details are worth considering.

+1. Much study has gone into this. Great work.

@user111403, Yes, those are reasonable points that I've considered. Other possibilities that I've calculated include that the New Jerusalem would be at a geostationary orbit around the earth, as a second moon orbiting the earth, or even in the Moon itself. The text provides the height of the walls as 144 cubits, which is about the height of a four-story building. To have enough oxygen for very tall building, if required, would require pressurization. A larger planet would be problematic with regard to greatly increased gravity and air pressure. So, I believe God will simply remodel our planet.

The question is based on assumptions about the correct way to read Revelation, and I believe those assumptions are wrong.
For the question to even be possible, we have to read the Bible physically. We read the word Jerusalem and assume it must be a physical city. We read about a tree of life and assume it must be some sort of actual tree. After all, this whole problem only exists because the city is big and one actual tree in one location can't provide life to people living on the other side of the city. Can it?
But this is a bad way to read Revelation. The key here is to understand that Revelation is describing spiritual reality, not physical reality. We have here pictures. In fact, we have pictures of truths that are beyond our ability to see. We need to use common sense, but more than that, we need to use our imagination.
Consider this very simple example. In John's gospel Jesus says this:

I am the true vine, and my Father is the gardener. 2 He cuts off every branch in me that bears no fruit, while every branch that does bear fruit he prunes so that it will be even more fruitful.
John 15:1-2, NIV

Now, who thinks from this verse that Jesus was made of wood? If you think that's a stupid question, I would agree with you. But I offer this example because I have had exactly this discussion with a non-Christian friend. His argument was that the Bible couldn't be true because of verses like John 15.1 saying obvious nonsense about Jesus.
So in response to this question I would begin by saying that Jerusalem is not 4,000 miles square. I presume this measurement comes from the description in Revelation 21:

16 The city was laid out like a square, as long as it was wide. He measured the city with the rod and found it to be 12,000 stadia in length, and as wide and high as it is long. 17 The angel measured the wall using human measurement, and it was 144 cubits thick.
Revelation 21:16-17 NIV

I urge readers to read this in the context of the whole of Revelation 21. It is come down from heaven, so it's spiritual. It is the bride of Christ. It is the dwelling place of God. It is made of pure gold. It has walls made of monster-sized precious metals. Surely this is not meant to be taken literally. It's meant to be taken more than literally. This is John's desperate attempt to describe the absolute perfection of God dwelling with humanity in a restored creation.
In this context, the numbers are surely symbolic. They apply to length, depth, and height, so if we take them literally we're not looking at a city. We are looking at a cube-shaped box. But in fact the number is 12,000, which in the setting of Revelation has to point to the 12 tribes of Israel. In other words, John is describing a city which is big, and it is made especially for God's chosen people. That's the meaning of the number.
As for the tree of life, this picture is equally symbolic, equally pictorial. (For one thing, it's one tree growing on both sides of a river.) To have access to the tree of life is simply to have access to the life that God offers, which is through Jesus Christ. All who come to God through Jesus will have the life lost in Genesis but finally restored when the last chapter of God's salvation story is told.

Thank you for your answer. If the New Jerusalem is spiritual, why would the righteous be resurrected with mortal bodies? According to Romans 8:11: "And if the Spirit of him who raised Jesus from the dead is living in you, he who raised Christ from the dead will also give life to your MORTAL BODIES because of his Spirit who lives in you." (NIV). Paul mentioned in 1 Cor 15:35-58, the righteous will be raised with a spiritual body. Why doesn't Paul say "spiritual being"?

This whole discussion has to do with the way we use language. I'm trying to get across the idea that when we talk about God-stuff (heaven, hell, eternity, God, Spirit etc) we need to do a big mental shift. Your question tells me I didn't do a very good job! For example, I don't think that my future spiritual body will be non-physical. I think it will be physical-plus, far more than physical. It's not exclusion, it's unimaginable addition and expansion. It's the same with heaven...(see next comment)

(continued) If we try to read Rev 21-22 as a city more or less the same as historical Jerusalem (eg thinking that we really are limited to a space of a few thousand square miles - bigger but still the same basic thing) we miss John's point. He saw something that was a million, gazillion times more glorious, something that mere human language is really inadequate to do justice to. That's the problem I have with most so called "literal" interpretations: they are often so weak :)

I believe your concept of a "physical plus" body is truly beyond imagination. I respect your perspective though.

Well, if it helps, the Christian worldview even in this life is that we are more than "just a body." We have a spiritual side as well. I try to take that seed and imagine (very poorly) what it will be like in a perfected world. All I'm trying to do in this discussion is help you with your thinking: If the New Jerusalem is spiritual, why would the righteous be resurrected with mortal bodies? That's a false division. We will be resurrected with perfect bodies, and they will be both spiritual and mortal (=physical). No separation. Spiritual does not equal non-physical.
